# How to fix badRequest error 400 in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a folder using Terraform but when i run `terraform apply` I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> Error: Error applying plan:
>
> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> * module.create_infra_setup.google_folder.new_folder: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> * google_folder.new_folder: Error creating folder 'tf-folder-test-1' in 'xxxxx.com': googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
> ```
>
> where xxxx.com is Org name

Here is the main.tf calling the module:

```
module "create_infra_setup" {
        source                  = "../modules/global/"
        folder_name             = "${var.var_folder_name}"
}
```

Here is the snippet of the resource in the module:

```
resource "google_folder" "new_folder" {
        display_name = "${var.folder_name}"
        parent = "${var.organization}"
}
```

Here is the terraform.tfvars parameter definition:

```
var_folder_name                 = "tf-folder-test-1"
```

Is this permissions issue of the svc account I'm using? The account has `Folder admin` privileges at org level.

Comment: What's the value of `var.organization`? It must be either `folders/some_folder_id` or `organizations/some_org_id` i.e. don't forget to include the folders / organizations prefix in the parent value. See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_folder.html#parent

Comment: Thanks for the help. Found the solution. I was mistakenly using org_name instead of org_id. Devil is in the details as they say.